# How can i see the previous records?

Tags: java

```
     public static BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static int recno=0, recsize, choice, i=0, k=1;
    public static String ans;


     public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Records: ");
        recsize = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String EmpNo[] = new String[recsize];
        String EmpName[] = new String[recsize];
        String Salary[] = new String[recsize];

        display_menu(EmpNo, EmpName, Salary,recno);
    }
```

How can i repeat this ?  System.out.print("\nDo you want to see the next record ? [press p]"); For example i will put 3 records and want to see the other previous records until i reach in the first record.

```
        public static void pre_Rec(String EmpNo[], String EmpName[], String Salary[], int recno) throws IOException{

                String pre;
            System.out.print("\nEmployee Number: "+EmpNo[recno]);
            System.out.print("\nEmployee Number: "+EmpName[recno]);
            System.out.print("\nEmployee Number: "+Salary[recno]);
            System.out.print("\nDo you want to see the next record ? [press p]");
            pre = reader.readLine();


            if(pre!="p"){
                recno--;
                System.out.print("\nEmployee Number: "+EmpNo[recno]);
                System.out.print("\nEmployee Number: "+EmpName[recno]);
                System.out.print("\nEmployee Number: "+Salary[recno]);

                 }
                      System.out.println ("\n\nDo you want to go back in the Display Menu ? [y/n]: ");
                      ans = reader.readLine();
                      if (ans.equals("y")){
                      display_menu(EmpNo, EmpName, Salary,recno);
                    }
                      else{
                      System.out.println("Thank You for Using this Program!");
                    }


            }
```

Comment: use a `do`-`while`loop

Comment: Your are looking for a "loop". Search for "java loop" and think of your condition "until"

Comment: @user1885518 there is no `until` loop in java.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes you are right, but i did not mention an "until loop". I think he will learn more, if he gets to know all kinds of loops and has to select the right one himself

Comment: What is it with two questions? You need to press p to view previous record. When should the second question be shown? "Do you want to go back in the Display Menu ? [y/n]:"? When user does not enter p?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I would like to help you but your description is very vague and confusing could you please make a list describing the steps that this program is intended to do. I looked at your code and from I could gather from your description this may help.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Records: ");
    int numOfRecords = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int x = 0; x <= numOfRecords; x++) {
    String EmpNo[] = new String[numOfRecords];
    String EmpName[] = new String[numOfRecords];
    String Salary[] = new String[numOfRecords];
   }

   //Whatever else you want to do
```

Comment: This is bad style: "=" is no comperator, use "==", but you don't have to use it anyway, just while(counter) would be enough. Furthermore you just provided an inifinity-loop

Comment: Oh gosh! I didn't even notice my mistakes I will edit